# In joining 2 tables, do the WHERE clauses reduce the table sizes before or after the join occurs?

Tags: sql, teradata

For example, does the first query get processed different than the second query?

**Query 1**

```
SELECT t1.var1, t2.var2 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t2.ID = 'ABCD'
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT t1.var1, t2.var2 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT var2, key from table2
           WHERE ID = 'ABCD'
           ) t2
ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE t2.ID = 'ABCD'
```

At a glance, it seems as if the second query would be more efficient - table2 is reduced before the join begins, whereas the first query appears to join the tables first, then reduce later. I'm using teradata, if it matters.

Comment: The two queries should be identical in performance.  Teradata has a good SQL optimizer, so you can trust it to do the right thing, particularly for such a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on vendor, version and configuration.
Teradata older version/legacy configuration might spool the sub-query as a first stage for Query 2 leading to **reduced** performance in comparison to Query 1 in depends with the table's' primary indexes and join algorithm.
I would suggest to avoid this kind of "optimization".

P.s.

1. Check if you get the same execution plan for both plans or different execution plans.
2. Check the query log for AMPCPUTime (for start)